# Trigger SendGrid message (Azure Functions) when Storage Table is added to

Tags: .net, azure, sendgrid, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that successfully queues storage table records as I can see in Azure Storage Explorer.

I have an Azure Function that successfully sends messages through SendGrid, and *is supposed* to trigger when the aforementioned queue is added to, but it does not.

I'm guessing there's a config issue. They're both in the same Function app and using the same connection string, but the SendGrid Function doesn't trigger. Both the functions themselves are vanilla minus my email address changes. Is there some other config to use?

### HttpPost(CRUD)-CSharp1

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "function"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outTable",
      "tableName": "orders",
      "connection": "matching_connection_string",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

### SendGridCSharp1

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "message",
      "direction": "out",
      "subject": "",
      "text": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "name": "order",
      "queueName": "orders",
      "connection": "matching_connection_string",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

### Update per @DAXaholic's answer

DAXaholic suggested I was writing to a table but triggering from a queue. I updated my outbound config (changed the last binding type to `queue`) and I'm receiving an error about not knowing which constructor to use: `Function ($HttpPOST(CRUD)-CSharp1) Error: Can't figure out which ctor to call.` I tried changing the namespace to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue`, but that didn't seem to have an effect.

Code below:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ICollector<Order> outTable, TraceWriter log)
{
    var formData = await req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.Get("Name")))
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {
           error = "no 'Name' property" 
        });
    }

    string name = formData["Name"].ToString();

    outTable.Add(new Order()
    {
        PartitionKey = "Functions",
        RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        OrderId = string.Format("order{0}", name),
        CustomerName = name,
        CustomerEmail = string.Format("{0}@{1}.com", name, name)
    });
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}

public class Order : TableEntity
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is your trigger is based on a Azure Storage Queue but you are writing to an Azure Storage Table so the former is not triggered. That said, try to replace the outbound binding to the Azure Storage Table with a binding to an appropriate queue like so (see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage.md#-azure-storage-queue-output-binding) as a reference)

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "function"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "name": "outTable",
      "queueName": "orders",
      "connection": "matching_connection_string",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

### Update outbound code to:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ICollector<Order> outQueue, TraceWriter log)
{
    var formData = await req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.Get("Name")))
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {
           error = "no 'Name' property" 
        });
    }

    string name = formData["Name"].ToString();

    outQueue.Add(new Order()
    {
        OrderId = string.Format("order{0}", name),
        CustomerName = name,
        CustomerEmail = string.Format("{0}@{1}.com", name, name)
    });
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think that makes sense. I updated the config, and there's some new error about not knowing which constructor to use (see updated post.)

Comment: Well of course you have to change your code so that you don't write Azure Storage Table entities but queue items - see their docs for that https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-storage/

Comment: The section on `Azure Storage queue output binding` uses a queue trigger to write a message, but I'm using HTTP post trigger (or trying to.) I'm not sure I can relate my use case to the documentation.

Comment: Well your current problem is related to the outbound binding which you originally wrote for Azure Storage Table but now it is for Azure Storage Queue so the example should match your use case, as the trigger is strictly speaking not relevant for your issue.

Comment: Try remove the inheritance from `TableEntity` in your `Order` class as you don't write to Azure Storage Table anymore.

Comment: Nailed it. I updated your answer with the code changes that ended up working!

Comment: Nice to hear that!